# Full Width - Normal Height BG Img

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have been over and over all the pages on google looking for some code that will help me fix my stretch width background image. I'm looking to make my background image fit all browser resolutions width, the height must remain the height it is on the image.

So far my code has given me a full width background but didn't stretch the image so its full width but the image didn't budge.

```
body{
background-color:#575c70;
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/1MS4u4y.jpg');
height: auto;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Full width and constant height:

```
background-size: 100% 1340px;
```